# Programmatically identify branch vs lightweight tag vs annotated tag

Tags: bash, git

I'm writing a Bash script to output info about references in multiple Git repositories.  So far it looks like this -

```
# paths that have Git repos
paths[0]="./playground"
paths[1]="./sandbox"

# reference objects common to all repos
references[0]="main"
references[1]="v1"
references[2]="v2"
references[3]="v3"

echo "Object type of reference in each repository -"
for reference in "${references[@]}"
do
    echo "~~~ $reference ~~~"
    for path in "${paths[@]}"
    do
        OBJECT_TYPE=$(git -C "$path" cat-file -t "$reference")
        if [ "$OBJECT_TYPE" = "tag" ]; then
            prefix="annotated"
        #else
            #TODO: implement logic for lightweight tags, branches
        fi
        echo "$prefix $OBJECT_TYPE $path"
    done
    echo
done
```

The annotated tag part is working correctly.  However, the `$OBJECT_TYPE` for branches and lightweight tags are both "commit", which is as expected, but not helpful for identifying which references are branches and which are lightweight tags.  How can they be distinguished?

Comment: Note that it's pretty typical not to *care* whether something is a branch name vs a lightweight tag name. One place you need to care is with `git checkout` / `git switch`: checkout will give you a detached HEAD with a tag name, and `git switch` will demand the `--detach` flag to use a tag (but allow `--detach` with a branch name, resulting in a detached HEAD there too, so that's usually what to do). A lot depends on *why* you're doing this: it's often best to just resolve the name to a hash ID with `git rev-parse`, and do everything with the hash ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only deal with the usual short names for tags and branches (e.g: `master` and `v1`, as opposed to `refs/heads/master` or `refs/tags/v1`), you can check whether the existing ref if `refs/heads/<name>` or `refs/tags/<name>` :

```
#!/bin/bash

is_branch () {
   local path=$1
   local name=$2

   # use git rev-parse to check if 'refs/heads/$name' exists
   #  * '-q' silences the errors
   #  * if it finds the reference, 'rev-parse' always prints the resulting sha on stdout
   #    (no option to silence that), hence the '> /dev/null'
   git -C "$path" rev-parse --verify -q refs/heads/"$name" > /dev/null
   return $?
}

is_tag () {
   local path=$1
   local name=$2

   git -C "$path" rev-parse --verify -q refs/tags/"$name" > /dev/null
   return $?
}

# or the shorter versions :
is_branch () {
    git -C "$1" rev-parse --verify -q refs/heads/"$2" > /dev/null
}
is_tag () {
    git -C "$1" rev-parse --verify -q refs/tags/"$2" > /dev/null
}


if is_branch "$path" "$reference"; then
  echo "'$reference' is a branch in '$path'"
fi
if is_tag "$path" "$reference"; then
  echo "'$reference' is a tag in '$path'"
fi
```

Comment: In the long versions what is `return $?`?

Comment: `$?` is the exit code of the last command you executed, `return $?` is to explicitly indicate that this function returns with that code. In this example it just makes for an explicit return value : if you don't specify a return value in a bash function, it is set to the exit code of the last executed command.

Comment: Note that you can also use `git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name <shortname>`, e.g., `git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name main`. This does the six-step lookup described in [gitrevisions](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) and tells you what the full name was, if there was one. Add `--verify` and/or redirect stderr to `/dev/null` (experiment with both, with invalid names, to see the effects).

Comment: Once you've determined that some ref (short or otherwise) is a tag name, use the hash ID you get from `git rev-parse` to see if the selected object is a tag object. If so, you have an annotated tag. If not, you have a lightweight tag. A lightweight tag is any tag name that points directly to a commit, tree, or blob object. A normal annotated tag points to an annotated tag object whose `tag` string matches the tag name.

Comment: You can make oddball annotated tags with various plumbing commands, but as far as I know, nobody really cares if tag `v123` is an annotated tag with `tag v321` inside it.

Answer (score 1):

```
git for-each-ref refs/heads --points-at "${reference}" --format="%(refname)" | grep refs/heads/${reference}
git for-each-ref refs/tags --points-at "${reference}" --format="%(refname)" | grep refs/tags/${reference}
```

The command lists all tags and branches that point at the reference commit. Without `--format="%(refname)"`, the output is like

```
96e195a92048272cdabd2992a21593bb3774e508 commit refs/heads/master
96e195a92048272cdabd2992a21593bb3774e508 commit refs/tags/nice
```

With it, it's like

```
refs/heads/master
refs/tags/nice
```

Test if the grep result is equal to the reference.

```
branch=$(git for-each-ref refs/heads --points-at "${reference}" --format="%(refname)" | grep refs/heads/${reference})
tag=$(git for-each-ref refs/tags--points-at "${reference}" --format="%(refname)" | grep refs/tags/${reference})
if [[ "${branch}" = refs/heads/${reference} ]];then
    prefix="branch"
elif [[ "${tag}" = refs/tags/${reference} ]];then
    prefix="lightweight"
else
    prefix="unknown"
fi
```

Multiple references may point at the same commit, so here `grep` is used to filter the output of `git for-each-ref`.

The if-else cannot work well if the repository happens to have both `refs/heads/foo` and `refs/tags/foo`. But this naming should always be avoided.